# Evaluate integral limits using the antiderivatives expression, with a calculator

Tags: calculator, calculus, ti-nspire

**THE QUESTION IS**

Is there a compact way to evaluate an antidevivative expression: `x**3 / 2 | x = a; x = b`

When we have an indefinite integral of the form:

```
# Pseudocode as I cannot write it in math mode
expr = x**2; a = 1; b = 5;
F = integral(expr, x); # integral of expr
Definite_integral = F.subs(x, b) - F.subs(x, a);
```

We can also do this by just using the built-in integrate function

```
# Pseudocode
expr = x**2;
a = 1; b = 5;
Definite_integra = integrate(expr, x, a, b) # integrate expr from a to b
```

However, the problem is that I start with an expression for the antiderivative

```
x**3 / 3
```

Ideally, I'd just want to express it with itegration brackets, example: [image: integration brackets]
I don't want to repeat myself and write the expression twice and I don't really want to declare the expression as a (unnecessary; only used unce) function just to express it as: `f(b) - f(a)` or more in line with Ti Nspire notation: `f(x)|x=b - f(x)|x=a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `bracket` using a little helper function.
The screenshot below is from the Notes area.

[image]